# Complex types for properties in defineProps in Vue

Tags: typescript, vue.js, vuejs3, vue-composition-api, vue-script-setup

In my code I have (or would like) to use complex prop types at some points.Below is an example of what I have in mind:

```js
enum Country {
  [...]
}

interface IPerson {
  firstname: string;
  lastname: string;

}

interface IAddress {
  street: string;
  houseNo: string;
  city: string;
  postalCode: string;
  country: number;
}

interface ITestComponentProps {
  person: IPerson;
  addresses: Array<IAddress>;
}
```

Then what I want to use this all for in `TestComponent.vue` is:

```js
[...]
const props = defineProps<ITestComponentProps>();
[...]
```

what I would expect now is some kind of error message or anything that tells me I have not provided the props in the right structure when trying something like this:

```js
[...]
<TestComponent :props="'foo'" />
[...]
```

In the documentation for Vue it is stated the following:

> Currently complex types and type imports from other files are not supported. It is possible to support type imports in the future.

---

Does anybody know if there is a workaround to get that desired behavior or when complex types will be supported?

Comment: Vue prop types are loosely checked at runtime, i.e. an array. If you really need to do more specific runtime checks like Array<IAddress>, you'll need to use schema validation that has a good support for TS, e.g. Zod, preferably not in props (can be done through custom prop validation function) but earlier, in places where typed data originates like api calls. So at the time when you pass addresses array as a prop you'll be quite sure that it can be only an array of address objects and not anything else

Answer (score 7):

In **Vue version < 3.3**, the following syntax :

```js
const props = defineProps<ITestComponentProps>();
```

supports only :

- A type literal
- A reference to an interface or a type literal in the same file

It's recommended to use the other syntax :

```js
import {PropType} from 'vue'

const props=defineProps({
       person:{
          type:Object as PropType<Person>
       }
  })
```

since this syntax :

- Works in Options API as well as composition API, with or without script setup
- Is a bit more to type, yes.
- gives you runtime warnings when passing the wrong (basic) type (i.e. string -instead of number).
- Works with imported props objects as well.

credit to **Linus borg** [in this comment](https://github.com/vuejs/core/issues/4294#issuecomment-1025210436)

Comment: Thanks!
At least the check for custom complex types works now. But what I am still missing is that I get an error when trying to pass an invalid proptype to a component. All I get now is a `[Vue warn]` in the browsers developer console

Comment: Oo that's a little funky. I might have to bookmark this page.

Comment: @dmodliba what's that warning?

Comment: @BoussadjraBrahim `[Vue warn]: Invalid prop: type check failed for prop "id". Expected String with value "0", got Number with value 0.`

Comment: I think you're doing something like `:id=""` instead of `id=""`

Comment: yeah exactly, I am trying to bind this as a prop (`id` is probably not that good of an example but the same happens if I would provide a string as a prop `person` which is expected to be an object)
What I would expect from my compiler is that it would not let me compile or throws errors if provided and expected prop types do not match and not just a warning in the browsers developer console.
Is there any way to get this with Vue 3?